# Joomla Menu Assignment not working, after adding custom .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, joomla

I had created a component 'com_listings' in which users can add their flats.

Presently the url is (working perfectly fine):

```
http://example.com/index.php?option=com_listings&view=space&layout=details&id=32
```

Added Rule to .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^listings/([0-9]+)$ index.php?option=com_listings&view=space&layout=details&id=$1 [NC,L]
```

New Clean Url

```
http://example.com/listings/14
```

In new Url all the modules are shown, which are displayed on home page, Please guide me where I am doing wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You don't use `.htaccess` in Joomla to create SEF URLs, the default `.htaccess` already sets up things for Joomla to be able to route requests to the right component, your extra rule is probably breaking that.

Joomla components have a [`router.php` file that is called to generate the SEF URL](http://docs.joomla.org/Supporting_SEF_URLs_in_your_component), you can read about it on the [Joomla Doc's](http://docs.joomla.org/) website.

When you generate a link in your PHP you pass the raw URL (your first URL for example) through `JRoute::_()`.

e.g.

$url = JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_listings&view=space&layout=details&id=32');

This will put SEF style URL into `$url`

Comment: Agree but that's not solve my problem.. using JRoute I get URL like http://example.com/component/listings/32/details/space

and I need url to be like:
http://example.com/listings/32

Is there any way to override Joomla Router and add new rule, Thanks

Comment: Thanks, your link to joomla docs, provide Guidance to write a Router for Custom Component.